# MS Works inventory formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

In MS Works I  would like to count the number of times a #1 comes up in a column.
In another field I would like to know the number of times a #2 is present and so on up to the # 4 appears.

Can someone give me a formula for this?
It should be simple but I can not find it anywhere.

Comment: What now, Works or Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If it's excel, you're looking for the `=countif()` [formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx)